# Want to display only last 3 digits number in textbox in ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2012

I am getting output from sql is like `1011153, 1011154, 101155`. I want to display only last 3 digits in like `153, 154, 155` respectively.

I'am using SSRS reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you what you are looking for:

```
=Cint(Right(Cstr(Fields!ID.Value),3))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply write:

```
=Right(Fields!YourID.Value, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, It Works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!your_field.Value.ToString().Length > 3, Fields!your_field.Value.ToString().Substring(Fields!your_field.Value.ToString().Length - 3, Fields!your_field.Value)
```

Comment: Note that if the field has less than 3 digits this will result as `#Error`

Comment: @Sébastien Sevrin, you are right! I changed expression in my answer.